# What is the way to group only those identical groups that are adjacent to each other in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

Input:

```
   Column1    Event   Time
0   type1     A       2020-11-01 05:26:12
1   type1     A       2020-11-01 05:26:17
2   type1     A       2020-11-01 05:26:22
3   type1     B       2020-11-01 05:26:32
4   type1     B       2020-11-01 05:26:37
5   type1     A       2020-11-01 05:26:42
6   type1     A       2020-11-01 05:26:47
7   type1     C       2020-11-01 05:26:52
8   type1     C       2020-11-01 05:27:02
9   type1     B       2020-11-01 05:27:07
10  type1     B       2020-11-01 05:27:15
```

Desired output:

```
    Column1   Event   Min(Time)             Max(Time)            EventEndTime

0   type1     A       2020-11-01 05:26:12   2020-11-01 05:26:22  2020-11-01 05:26:32
1   type1     B       2020-11-01 05:26:32   2020-11-01 05:26:37  2020-11-01 05:26:42
2   type1     A       2020-11-01 05:26:42   2020-11-01 05:26:47  2020-11-01 05:26:52
3   type1     C       2020-11-01 05:26:52   2020-11-01 05:27:02  2020-11-01 05:27:07
4   type1     B       2020-11-01 05:27:07   2020-11-01 05:27:15
```

I have tried but could not able to group only those identical events that are adjacent and I ended up getting an overall min and max values by below line of code:

```
 data.groupby(['Column1','Event']).agg({'Time': ['min','max']})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use helper Series with compare shifted values with cumulative sums to `g` and for aggregate are used named aggregations in dictionary, so is used unpack `**`, last remove third level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
g = data['Event'].ne(data['Event'].shift()).cumsum()

d = {'Min(Time)': ('Time', 'min'), 'Max(Time)': ('Time', 'max')}
df = (data.groupby(['Column1','Event', g], sort=False)
          .agg(**d)
          .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
          .reset_index())
print (df)
  Column1 Event           Min(Time)           Max(Time)
0   type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:12 2020-11-01 05:26:22
1   type1     B 2020-11-01 05:26:32 2020-11-01 05:26:37
2   type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:42 2020-11-01 05:26:47
3   type1     C 2020-11-01 05:26:52 2020-11-01 05:27:02
4   type1     B 2020-11-01 05:27:07 2020-11-01 05:27:15
```

If want create helper column:

```
data['groups'] = data['Event'].ne(data['Event'].shift()).cumsum()
print (data)
   Column1 Event                Time  groups
0    type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:12       1
1    type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:17       1
2    type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:22       1
3    type1     B 2020-11-01 05:26:32       2
4    type1     B 2020-11-01 05:26:37       2
5    type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:42       3
6    type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:47       3
7    type1     C 2020-11-01 05:26:52       4
8    type1     C 2020-11-01 05:27:02       4
9    type1     B 2020-11-01 05:27:07       5
10   type1     B 2020-11-01 05:27:15       5

d = {'Min(Time)': ('Time', 'min'), 'Max(Time)': ('Time', 'max')}
df = (data.groupby(['Column1','Event', 'groups'], sort=False)
          .agg(**d)
          .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
          .reset_index())
print (df)
  Column1 Event           Min(Time)           Max(Time)
0   type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:12 2020-11-01 05:26:22
1   type1     B 2020-11-01 05:26:32 2020-11-01 05:26:37
2   type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:42 2020-11-01 05:26:47
3   type1     C 2020-11-01 05:26:52 2020-11-01 05:27:02
4   type1     B 2020-11-01 05:27:07 2020-11-01 05:27:15
```

EDIT: If need next event per groups:

```
df['EventEndTime'] = df.groupby('Column1')['Min(Time)'].shift(-1)

#next Event not per groups
#df['EventEndTime'] = df['Min(Time)'].shift(-1)

print (df)
  Column1 Event           Min(Time)           Max(Time)        EventEndTime
0   type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:12 2020-11-01 05:26:22 2020-11-01 05:26:32
1   type1     B 2020-11-01 05:26:32 2020-11-01 05:26:37 2020-11-01 05:26:42
2   type1     A 2020-11-01 05:26:42 2020-11-01 05:26:47 2020-11-01 05:26:52
3   type1     C 2020-11-01 05:26:52 2020-11-01 05:27:02 2020-11-01 05:27:07
4   type1     B 2020-11-01 05:27:07 2020-11-01 05:27:15                 NaT
```

Comment: Event column is getting converted into numbers form  as there are so many events like A, B, AA, XYZ, D, etc , it is creating confusion.

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai - yes, it seems you use `['Column1', g]` instead `['Column1','Event', g]`

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai - Or wrongly assigned colulumn back like `data['Event'] = data['Event'].ne(data['Event'].shift()).cumsum()`, if want assign back use another column like `data['groups'] = data['Event'].ne(data['Event'].shift()).cumsum()` and then instead `['Column1','Event', g]` use `['Column1','Event', 'groups']`

Comment: Got it and If I want to fetch event end time also then? Definition of eventend is time when the next event starts! shift(-1) will work?

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai - Not sure if understand, can you add expected output?

Comment: added, check now!

Comment: This answered my question. Thanks! :)